# How to add punctuation marks for the sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, tokenize

How to approach the problem of building a **Punctuation Predictor?**

The working demo for the question can be found in this [link](http://bark.phon.ioc.ee/punctuator).

**Input Text is as below:**

```
"its   been   a   little   while   Kirk   tells   me its   actually   been
three   weeks   now   that Ive   been   using   this   device   right   here
that   is   of   course   the   Galaxy   S   ten   I mean   Ive   just   been
living   with   this phone   this   has   been   my   phone   has   the   SIM
card   in   it   I   took   photos I   lived   live   I   sent   tweets whatsapp
slack   email   whatever   other   app   this   was my   smart phone"
```

Comment: maybe you can start by creating a list. first  element first word, 2nd element the first two words, 3rd element the first 3 words, 4th element the first 4 words....

Comment: I thought about it but it will not work for my case. I will have thousands of words depending on the file I am processing. Consider I have a thousand words file to process and the N-gram method which you are suggestion will have 1000 sentence to analyze. But If I divide the sentence I would be analyzing only around 100-200 sentences.

Comment: Sorry, you can’t just replace one question with an entirely different one, especially when there are already answers. I’ve rolled back the post to the original question posted. Unaccepting the answer is especially unfair to the effort they put into answering your question.

Answer (score 3):

Predicting punctuation for text (in particular for speech transcriptions) is a well-known problem.

You could try using [Punctuator2](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2), either with the provided models or by training new models for text from your domain. Look at the bottom of the README for pointers to some related projects.

Grammarly developed a simpler approach for only inserting periods between run-on sentences, described here:

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/nlp-run-on-sentences/

They did some nice experiments with real vs. artificial training data, which is useful because it's easy to generate training data from texts that you know have reliable punctuation at sentence boundaries, like newspaper text.

Comment: In Punctuator2 they have specified how to use their model. To use that we need to train, test and create a model though.

Comment: It's a bit buried (and I also don't think Europarl models will be great for your data), but there are links to download some of their models at the end of this section: https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2#how-well-does-it-work

Comment: I undeleted this because the question should not have been replaced with a different post, and I’m assuming that was the reason you deleted your answer. Feel free to re-delete if there was a different reason. However, if this answer helped the person that asked the question it can help others with the same or similar issues. I’d leave the answer up for them to find and perhaps vote on.

Comment: That's fine, thanks! I'm glad the original question was restored.